# Why my header files can't correctly index each other's declaration dependency with clangd in VSCode?

Tags: c++, c

I'm now codeing C/C++ in VSCode with clangd.There are some annoying problems.For example,I defined a variable in "a.h",which also used in "b.h".But it will error in b.h with:

> "Unknown type name 'xxxxx'clang(unknown_typename)".

Actually it doesn't affect the compliling results,But always lots of annoying red waves there.

```
//in "a.h"
typedef unsigned long uint64;
```

```
//in "b.h"
uint64 abc; //Error here： (Unknown type name 'uint64'clang(unknown_typename)
```

```
//in "xxx.c"
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

abc=1; // Correct here
```

I have only used "complile_commands.json" to configure clangd.It's run good that I can easily jump to definition or declaration.Is there anything more for clangd I need to configure?

(PS: here is my clangd's settins)

```
"clangd.onConfigChanged": "restart",
    "clangd.arguments": [
        "--clang-tidy",
        "--clang-tidy-checks=performance-*,bugprone-*",
        "--compile-commands-dir=${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/",
        "--background-index",
        "--completion-style=detailed",
        "--enable-config",
        "--function-arg-placeholders=false",
        "--all-scopes-completion",
        "--header-insertion-decorators",
        "--header-insertion=never",
        "--log=verbose",
        "--pch-storage=memory",
        "--pretty",
        "--ranking-model=decision_forest",
        "--cross-file-rename",
        "-j=16"
    ],
    "clangd.checkUpdates": false,
```

Comment: You have to add `#include "a.h"` in file `b.h` to use `uint64`. Just add `#include "a.h"` at the top of file `b.h` after the include guards(if any). The program then [works here](https://onlinegdb.com/EUxxKjQ9Z).

Comment: Inside `b.h` the type `uint64` is not known, the error is valid. Why not use `stdint`?

Comment: As an aside, there are no guarantees that an `unsigned long` is 64 bits. [Arithmetic types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types)

Comment: use the int types from: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with VScode or clangd.

Instead, the problem is that in file `b.h` you have not included `a.h` and thus `uint64` is unknown at the point where you're using it `uint64 abc;`.

To solve this, you need to include `a.h` before using `uint64`:

**a.h**

```
#pragma once 
typedef unsigned long uint64;
```

**b.h**

```
#pragma once 
#include "a.h" //added this

uint64 abc;  //works now
```